# Building Xamarin.Forms app in mobile Center

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, mobile-center, visual-studio-app-center

I have mobile center set to build from my git repo of my app but for some reason the build process does not recognize the using statement

```
 using System.Net.Http;
```

and for that reason it fails. is there something I'm not doing exactly?

Comment: Is your System.Net.Http.dll file missing?

Comment: Yes. it works when I'm working with visual studio, I only get this issue when I'm building using Mobile Center to build from my git repo in order to distribute to beta testers

Comment: It might not be in whatever you set your build-dir to be

Comment: Can you explain??

Comment: My dll is in visual studio's program files. If you copy it into your bin folder it may fix your problem

Comment: Do not copy it into your bin folder. Your bin folder should not be included in your source control

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay to solve this issue all I had to do was add as a Nuget Microsoft.Net.Http to my PCL project and it was able to build in mobile center without affecting my Visual Studio Project.

Answer (score 0):

Visual studio can automatically resolve some dll's. Check the references and make sure that you have added System.Net.Http reference.  If it is a PCL, make sure you add the [Nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Net.Http/).

Comment: So you're saying I should add the System.Net Nuget to my PCL project? ?

Comment: System.Net.Http does not exist in the default PCL profile. If your PCL project is the one that has "using System.Net.Http;" yes. If it is in another project type, ensure you have the reference for System.Net.Http and everything will start working.

Comment: this is the error I get when I add the nuget   Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error  Could not install package 'System.Net.Http 4.0.0'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets '.NETPortable,Version=v4.5,Profile=Profile259', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.   0